# Pooled Request in Python - Handling multiple output json

Tags: python, json

I have a piece of code I where I send a url request and then parse the json to get certain response variables as below.

```
request = requests.get(url)
result = json.loads(request.text)
```

I am trying to pool the request to take advantage of threading and can get the first part to work with the line below.

```
requests = pool.map(requests.get, urls)
```

However I tried to get the multiple results with the following two lines

```
results = pool.map(json.load, requests.text)
results = pool.map(json, requests)
```

Neither works with the former giving me "a list object has not attribute text" error and the latter saying that "the module object is not callable".

There's probably an easy trick to get this to work, but I can't seem to find it. Following step would be to parse the json to get an element, which I hope won't cause too much trouble either.

Comment: Is that `multiprocessing.Pool` or `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the returned value from `pool.map(..)` is a list and you don't have a `.text` attribute in it. Further, you need not fork off processes just to parse JSON from the response; doing it for 
just for HTTP requests is fine, I suppose. Use a plain old list comprehension instead to do in the main process.

```
responses = pool.map(requests.get, urls)
results = [json.loads(x.text) for x in responses]
```

Also, note that requests module can parse JSON for you, if you say:

```
results = [x.json() for x in responses()]
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but this is giving me the following AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: That should be `json.loads` and there may be a need to decode it also. Or... likely better, `results = [resp.json() for resp in responses]`

Comment: @DarknessFalls: There was a typo. Use `loads` instead of `load`. Better yet, use the second block of code.

Answer (score 0):

You have made an error in the second line

```
requests = pool.map(requests.get, urls)
```

Remember you have imported the requests module as `requests` and now you are assigning the result to `requests` variable.

Hence the error.

Comment: it supposed to be named `responses`